# Shared workbook - updating data before action

Tags: vba, excel

I have shared workbook in excel, so multiple users can change content. Sheet works as list of projects and tasks, which user can insert, edit and delete. Edit and delete works fine for multiple users, but i have issue with inserting. When two (or more users) insert new project/tasks (new rows appears) after save, there is huge conflict in whos data should be saved.

So i have an idea, that before each insertion i would like to load other user changes. Will be enough to use this line before each row insertion?

```
Application.CommandBars("Reviewing").Controls("&Update File").Execute
```

(i googled, that this line should trigger shared sheet update)

Or is here better aproach? Maybe after new line save sheet, etc?

Comment: i dont think there is an easy way... the only i can think of, is to let only vba insert cells... however, disable inserting cells also disables it for vba, and this property cant be changed as long as the workbook is shared. also there is no `BeforeInsertRows`-event or something like that. leaves only the 'show/hide lots of rows/columns' and disable 'insert/delete rows/columns'... maybe someone knows a trick with the API

Comment: @dirkReichel There isnt issue after inserting rows, im using buttons for this, so i know where to pin event. Im just not sure if command above before insert and save after will make the job done and if its correct aproach, or excel will explode after some time

Comment: oh ok... pls check my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33627668/multiple-pcs-running-excel-accessing-to-the-same-spreadsheet-in-the-server-how) ant tell me if that can solve your problem (you will not open the wb, but save and accept all other changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i made bit of testing and when i use

```
Application.CommandBars("Reviewing").Controls("&Update File").Execute
```

or

```
Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=455).Execute
```

changes wasnt refreshed correctly. 
Then i accidentaly found solution using basic saving (ALT + S) which have only issue which was prompting information about "Other user made change in excel.."

This lead to my correct solution, where im using

```
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

on macro start and at the end. On macro start because i need actual data from all users which have saved changes, so i get first empty row to which i can safely insert data and at the end so my change is saved for another users.

This also provides data refresh, when user edits previous data. Hope this will help someone in similar issue.